# Printing match from tree

Tags: java

I am trying to create a "word completion" tree java program from a dictionary that is a text file but I am not sure where to go from here. The word completion program will match any words that start with the string entered. I am new to java/ programming. I have designed the tree as a multi way tree with each node storing a character as a letter and a boolean variable to indicate if it is the end of the word (amongst other things).

I am at the point where I am trying to see if my reading in of the file into the tree is working correct. However when I try to print my tree, it is not working correctly. It is not displaying the first letter correctly in every word after the first word. Instead of reading in from file, for testing purposes I am simply adding only 4 words to tree (Base, Basement, Ma, Matthew).

So my question is can anyone tell me why it is not printing correctly AND what I need to do next in order to finish the word completion?

Thank you so much in advance to everyone for taking the time to help me with my problem

Comment: Please could you show your expected and actual output

Answer (score 0):

it's this part

```
    while(t!=null) {
    if(t.down!=null && t.right!=null) {
        //System.out.println(t.letter + " children");
        //System.out.print(t.letter);
        print(t.down);
    }
    t=t.right;
```

when you encounter another word you should print, you start it from `t.down`. You can for example, store all the letters up to that node on mutual stack, print them, and then proceed to printing other letters from tree.

Issue here is: `t.down` is next letter (from point of view of current node) in some other word.

Try adding more words with common starting substrings to understand my point easily.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. The printing is an issue right now but won't your suggestion be a problem when I try to make the program do its purpose, which is word competition

Comment: I can see word completion working in two ways:
1) When someone starts typing and you recognize you have some words with same start, you repeatedly (with another typed letter) ask if the typed word is one of suggested (ones you recognized from dictionary).
2) When you know that the typed word is the start of some word in dictionary (w/o ambiguity) you insert that word.

Comment: The same start is exactly what I am referring too. Do you mind providing me an example based on my code how this would be done? Thank you so much

Comment: In first case, that is exactly the expected behavior, where you should output all the words from their first letter.

In latter, it wouldn't make a difference, because you're going to print only one word (and you can make it replace typed word), and you wouldn't need this feature.

Comment: Sorry I am not following. What do you mean by I would not need the feature? Just to clarify, the user enters a word and I search my tree for all the words that begin with that word or match it exactly. Thanks again

Comment: you should add to your class `private static Dequeue<char> stack = new ArrayDequeue<char>();`, and in that `while(t!=null) {` in `print(TreeNode)`, you should put a letter to it (push) in every cycle (before calling `print(t.down)`), and print all chars from stack before starting to print letters from tree. (You can use `stack.toArray()` to get an array of letters you already stored.)

Comment: i'm typing blindly, there should probably be some modifications to this suggestion...
if you suggest to user word to autocomplete upon every typed letter, this should be one way to do it...